# Kurento Composite Grids Recording

Tags: java, node.js, ffmpeg, webrtc, kurento

I have 2 WebRtcEndpoint(caller&callee). Those endpoints are connected each other to share their streams.
There is no problem in this communication. Each peer gets the other peer's stream without any frame lost.

I want to record this two stream side by side. As a result of my search, kurento composite can be used to record caller and callee streams side by side. 
But this way of recording causes a lot of frame lost on the record file.

My implementation:

```
// To connect streams
callerWebrtcEndpoint.connect(calleeWebrtcEndpoint);
calleeWebrtcEndpoint.connect(callerWebrtcEndpoint);


//To create grids and to record output of composite element
callerWebrtcEndpoint.connect(callerHubPort);
calleeWebrtcEndpoint.connect(calleeHubPort);

recordHubPort.connect(recorderEndPoint)
```

Is there any alternative for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server that kurento works on does not have enough cpu. When I run kurento on machine with more cpu then records quality is increased.